# "Do you have any wine left?" Is this "have something done" or the past participle form of leave as an attributive

Tags: grammar, past-participles

In the sentence "Do you have any wine left?" I think left is the past participle form of the verb "leave" and it is now an adjective. 
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. We can use past participle as adjective. For example, I am excited.
About the question in the title, I think the full sentence is: 'Do you have any wine which is left?'. There is nothing in connection with 'have something done'.

Comment: I think there's more to it than just putting an adjective at the end. You could say "Do you have any wine open?" or "Do you have any wine poured?" but not "Do you have any wine red?" So clearly you can't use just any adjective at the end. It seems to relate to a change of state, but I'm not sure exactly what the grammatical structure is: it's not simply a case of appending an adjective to describe the wine.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I think I misunderstood his/her question. I think the grammar structure in this case is 'reduced relative clauses'.

Comment: It's the past participle of _leave_ in the sense _not use all of_.